# Canvas object positioning issue - JS

Tags: javascript, canvas, resize

l believe to have a error of sorts.

Visually, the button goes off the **SCREEN** instead of sitting in it's spot. The issue is the X positioning of the canvas object, being the `'<button>'`, as it moves off screen when you resize the browser window from the **LEFT** but also the button does **NOT MOVE** and **STAYS IN ITS PLACE** when resizing the browser window from the **RIGHT**.

Essentially, the canvas object, 'button', should be secured in one place so that it stays in the same spot no matter how big or small my browser's window is.

There is also a reproducible demo.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("c");

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var the_button = document.getElementById("the_button");
var the_background = document.getElementById("the_background");


var button_imageLeft = 1100;
var button_imageBottom = 150;
var button_imageWidth = 170;
var button_imageHeight = 100;
var button_offsetX, button_offsetY;

window.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(the_background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawButton();
}

initialize();


function initialize() {
  window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);
  resizeCanvas();
}

function drawButton() {
  button_offsetX = button_imageLeft;
  button_offsetY = canvas.height - button_imageBottom;
  ctx.drawImage(the_button, button_offsetX, button_offsetY, button_imageWidth, button_imageHeight);
}

function redraw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.drawImage(the_background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawButton();
}

function resizeCanvas() {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  redraw();
}

the_button_function = (event) => {
  const {
    x,
    y
  } = event;
  if ((x >= button_offsetX && x < (button_offsetX + button_imageWidth)) &&
    (y >= button_offsetY && y < (button_offsetY + button_imageHeight))) {
    alert("<Button>")

  }
}

canvas.addEventListener('click', (e) => the_button_function(e));
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>

<img style="display: none;" id="the_button" src="https://i.imgur.com/wO7Wc2w.png" />

<img style="display: none;" id="the_background" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/hand-painted-watercolor-background-with-sky-clouds-shape_24972-1095.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg" />

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting anchors on the bottom and left as far as I can see your code for placing the button is correct, the only reason why it will "move off screen" is because the size of the window is less than the left value, I made a few changes to your code.

If you are drawing images you should be using `onload` or you risk executing the `drawImage`  when the image is not really loaded yet, and that might make it look like it is off screen

```js
window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);
var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var btn = {left: 10, bottom: 60, width: 85, height: 50};
var btnImg = document.getElementById("the_button");
btnImg.onload = drawButton;
resizeCanvas()

function drawButton() {
  btn.x = btn.left;
  btn.y = canvas.height - btn.bottom;
  ctx.drawImage(btnImg, btn.x, btn.y, btn.width, btn.height);
}

function redraw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawButton();
}

function resizeCanvas() {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  redraw();
}

the_button_function = (event) => {
  const { x, y } = event;
  if ((x >= btn.x && x < (btn.x + btn.width)) &&
    (y >= btn.y && y < (btn.y + btn.height))) {
    alert("<Button>")
  }
}
canvas.addEventListener('click', (e) => the_button_function(e));
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>

<img style="display: none;" id="the_button" src="https://i.imgur.com/wO7Wc2w.png" />

</html>
```

Your code is only for left and bottom ...
If you wanted to instead anchor to the right and, top you will need to change your logic:

```
  btn.x = btn.left;
  btn.y = canvas.height - btn.bottom;
```

But as is it works fine for left bottom, I do not see a problem with that.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the provided solution. l see that the you have used an array of records, that you have added .onload to target loading in the btnimg first and added new logic that checks where x & y of the btn is located on the canvas. -Nevermind the question l asked (it was regarding the right and bottom logic).

Comment: How might l go about anchoring to the right and bottom, it seems that the native drawing inside the canvas is from the left instead.

Comment: Nevermind, l got it.

Added `canvas.width - btn.left` & left the record `left` inside `var btn` as a positive integer. You can also do `canvas.width + btn.left` but make the record `left` a negative integer.

Comment: @Bonked perfect making the left a negative integer is a nice approach ... but why not just instead of the `left` property use  `right` that will make it less confusing to others reading your code later